# A closed form of $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt[\phi]{x}\ \arctan x}{\left(x^\phi+1\right)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, golden-ratio

Is it possible to evaluate the following integral in a closed form?
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt[\phi]{x}\ \arctan x}{\left(x^\phi+1\right)^2}dx,$$
where $\phi$ is the [golden ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio):
$$\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}.$$

Comment: Numerical integration and [isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au) suggest $\frac\pi{4\,\phi}$.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Since $\frac1\phi=\phi-1$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt[\phi]{x}\,\arctan(x)}{\left(x^\phi+1\right)^2}\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\phi\arctan(x)}{\left(x^\phi+1\right)^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}\tag{1}\\
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\phi(\frac\pi2-\arctan(x))}{\left(x^\phi+1\right)^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Average $(1)$ and $(2)$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt[\phi]{x}\,\arctan(x)}{\left(x^\phi+1\right)^2}\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac\pi4\int_0^\infty\frac{x^\phi}{\left(x^\phi+1\right)^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}\tag{3}\\
&=\frac\pi{4\phi}\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{\left(x+1\right)^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}\tag{4}\\
&=\frac\pi{4\phi}\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:

$(1)$: $\frac1\phi=\phi-1$
$(2)$: Substitute $x\mapsto\frac1x$
$(3)$: Average $(1)$ and $(2)$
$(4)$: Substitute $x\mapsto x^{1/\phi}$
$(5)$: $\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(x+1)^2}=\left[-\frac1{x+1}\right]_0^\infty=1$

Comment: wow you're really fast . (+1)

Comment: Won't the limits be reversed? Or if remaining the same, there should be a minus sign. Did the inside simplification of the integral require a minus sign? (I'm not able to reach step 2 from step 1 after suggested substitution; could you please elaborate?)

Comment: $$ \begin{align} \int_0^\infty f(x)\,\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x} &= \int_\infty^0 f\left(\frac1x\right)\left(-\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}\right)\\ &=\int_0^\infty f\left(\frac1x\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x} \end{align} $$

Comment: Sigh.. Can't believe I forgot that.. thank you :)

Answer (score 22):

[robjohn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13854/robjohn)'s result can be generalized to all real $a\ne0$:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{a-1}\arctan x}{(x^a+1)^2}dx=\frac\pi{4\,|a|}.$$

Comment: The original question would translate as
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{1/a}\arctan(x)}{(x^a+1)^2}\mathrm{d}x
$$
It is $a=\phi$ that gives $1/a=a-1$. However, if you start from my second step, then your statement is true.

Answer (score 1):

**Integration by Parts**

Using $\phi^2=\phi+1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\phi}=\phi-1  $, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\frac{1}{\phi}} \arctan x}{\left(x^\phi+1\right)^2} d x 
&=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\phi-1} \arctan x}{\left(x^\phi+1\right)^2} d x \\
&=-\frac{1}{\phi} \int_0^{\infty} \arctan x d\left(\frac{1}{x^\phi+1}\right) \\
&=-  \underbrace{ \left[\frac{\arctan x}{\phi\left(x^\phi+1\right)}\right]_0^{\infty}}_{=0} +\frac{1}{\phi} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(1+x^2\right)\left(1+x^\phi\right)} d x \quad   \textrm{ via IBP} \\
\end{aligned}
$$

$$\begin{aligned}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(x^2+1\right)\left(x^\phi+1\right)} d x  &\stackrel{x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}}{=} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^\phi}{\left(1+x^2\right)\left(1+x^\phi\right)} d x
\\& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1+x^\phi}{\left(1+x^2\right)\left(1+x^\phi\right)} d x =\frac{\pi}{4}\\
\end{aligned} $$
Now we can conclude that
$$
 \boxed{\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\frac{1}{\phi}} \arctan x}{\left(x^\phi+1\right)^2} d x  =\frac{\pi}{4\phi} } $$